# PHP: Load large XML file

Tags: php, xml

I tried to read a file with many ways, but I always have unsuccessful attempts. I tried simplexml_load_string(always this function return false) with flag LIBXML_PARSEHUGE, [xml-string-streamer](https://github.com/prewk/xml-string-streamer) and others libraries.

My XML file is around 745 KB, with 18k lines. Anyone who solved this problem can help me? Thanks a lot.

A example of code:

```
$test = simplexml_load_file("eclipse.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```

Comment: What is your error? I wouldn't think a 745K file should cause issues, unless opening it multiple times.

Comment: The simplexml_load_string() function always return false and with LIBXML_PARSEHUGE flag. I don't know what do.

Comment: My code: $test = simplexml_load_file("eclipse.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Nothing in there :/

Comment: Does `file_get_contents` get the contents as a string for you?

Comment: Yes, But when I put in simplexml_load_file, returns false. :/

Comment: What about `new SimpleXMLElement($string)`, same result?

Comment: He returns nothing, when I put a small XML file, SimpleXMLElement works normally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115260/discussion-between-chris85-and-regis-zanandrea).